# Update multiple picture src from their different figcaption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the HTML I'm trying to put the src of the img files dynamically when loaded.

```
 <figure>
            <img src="" class="img-rounded"  width="220" height="221"> 
            <figcaption>Ubing</figcaption>
        </figure>


        <figure>
            <img src="" class="img-rounded"  width="220" height="221"> 
            <figcaption>Lalaki</figcaption>
        </figure>
 <figure>
            <img src="" class="img-rounded"  width="220" height="221"> 
            <figcaption>Babai</figcaption>
        </figure>
```

Here is the Jquery. Did I correctly  selected the img here? Does the jquery update all of this when it works?

```
$(document).load(function() {
     var ex = $('figcaption').text();
    $.post('../php/fetchLabel.php' , {input:ex} , function(data){
        if(data== false){
            $('this').prev().attr('alt','No Data In database');
        }
        else{
            $('this').prev().attr('src', '../'+data);
        }
})})
```

Someone please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).load(function() {
    $("figure").each(function(){
     var $figure = $(this);
     var ex = $figure.find('figcaption').text();
     var $image = $figure.find("img");
    $.post('../php/fetchLabel.php' , {input:ex} , function(data){
        if(data== false){
            $image.attr('alt','No Data In database');
        }
        else{
            $image.attr('src', '../'+data);
        }
})
})
})
```